# Is Copying & Paste a bad programming practice for Android Layouts GUI?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Recently, I've been developing a project where I used to **copy** and **paste** UI elements on the `AndroidLayout.xml`.

That's mainly because I was lazy enough to set all characteristics over and over again.

However, when updating the `@+id` references via GUI (Image 1), it also updates every item that has been copied.

[image]

*Image 1 - Updating via GUI*

Then, if you do that, you also update the image from another layout where you have copied the characteristics you desire for this *View*.

The solution was to copy and paste **only using code** (Image 2), and changing the `@+id` before saving the layout.

[image]

*Image 2 - Copying and paste via code*

I never had a problem with that before. Actually, I used to copy & paste via GUI for a long time with no problems.

After I've got it working on code, I began to wonder:

**Is using Copying & Paste on Android XML a bad programming practice? Why?**

Comment: Simply don't get it when people down vote and don't contribute for a better knowledge of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use styles.xml to avoid copy & paste elements in your xml layouts. Example:

Paste it in styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="main_layout">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And now each of your layout in xml files can be write without copy-paste:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_id_res"
    style="@style/main_layout">
</LinearLayout>
```